# Javascript create long number with epic length

Tags: javascript

I need to create a long random number with length min 0 and max 90000000000000000

ex: 23746589201948757493028

it is possibile?

Comment: Yes and no. You can create any number you want, but you will loose precision. The maximum "safe" integer value is `9007199254740991`.

Comment: Well if you don't actually need to *do* anything with the number, you can just generate a string of random digit characters. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just combine two functions with the maximum number to get it

Comment: *"Just combine two functions with the maximum number to get it"* I have the impression you are missing basic understanding of how numbers are represented in a program, but feel free to answer your own question with a working solution if you have one.

Comment: function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (min - max + 1)) + min;
}
alert(getRandomInt(0,999999999999) + getRandomInt(0,999999999999));

NIUB!

Comment: Uhm, `2 * 999999999999` is well in the range of `2^53`. So of course that works. You could also just use `getRandomInt(0, 1999999999998)` in that case (`2 * 999999999999  = 1999999999998`). However, the value you used in your example (`23746589201948757493028`) is much larger than what JS can represent (precisely). The maximum number of digits an integer can have is `16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. They are 64-bit floating point values, the largest exact integral value is 2<sup>53</sup>

or

9007199254740992

That said this is the max **exact** value if you don't care about floating point inaccuracies, which you probably should, you can use higher numbers.

See the spec for more details : http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5

Comment: Just combine two functions with the maximum number to get it

Comment: The issue with that is that you'll end up with floating point in accuracies. See here for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples